# Customer Report Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to have a custom report per minute for Google Analytics? So far I have found that it is possible to have a report per hour.

Comment: You may want to try asking this on the [Web Applications site](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

It's not available out of the box, but you could pass the minute level data as a custom variable with a single line of custom JavaScript

You'd pass it as a page-level custom variable (you'd put this before your `_trackPageview` call).

Assuming you're using the async syntax.

```
_gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 1, "Minute", ""+new Date().getMinutes(), 3]);
```

That would set a custom variable, with the key of `Minute`, and a value corresponding to the minute number (ie, `31`).

However, I'd caution against spending time on this; it seems unlikely to yield actionable results.